# Server Tags Cannot Contain <% ... %> Construct for href JavaScript Function

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have a JavaScript function which uses a session variable as a parameter.

```
<A href="javascript:showEquiSmartStateCountyEligibility('<%Response.Write(Session["TestAccName"]);%>')" runat="server">State Dependency</A>
```

The above code is throwing an error:

```
Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.
```

But the same code is working fine in .Net version 1.1.

Can you please point out what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different allowed approach such as:

```
<A href="" runat="server" id="yourID">State Dependency</A>
```

In the aspx.cs file, do:

```
yourID.Href = "javascript:showEquiSmartStateCountyEligibility('"   + Session["TestAccName"] + ")'";
```

Or omitting the runat attribute should make your approach work.